# Unity3D Changing texture at runtime not working on Android build

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I'm working on a digital book for an Android tablet on Unity 5. I'm using this [Page Curl](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/16880) plugin from the Asset Store.

I have 3 main planes: LeftPage, RightPage and TurningPage, and I keep an index of which page I'm looking for each one of this pages so I can manage the corresponding textures. When I click on one of the Left or Right pages, the turning page animation starts playing and when it ends, I update the index values and the corresponding textures.

It works perfect in Unity Editor and perfect with Unity Remote in the tablet, but when I run the installed apk, the turning page is always showing the textures assigned at the begining. The Left and Right pages work fine.

Printing the assigned texture name (*pageFront.mainTexture.name*) I get the correct texture which is equivalent to the page index value, but the turningPage keeps showing the initial (*indPage = 0*) texture.

All the textures are asigned on the editor on a Texture2D array.

```
    void Update()
{
     ...

     // If click is in one of four defined areas.
     if (mouseX > 970 && mouseX < 1024 && canFlipFwd)
     {
          if (mouseY > 250 && mouseY < 710)
          {
               clickCase = 1; // Play animation 1. 
               changePageFwd();
          }
          else if (mouseY > 50 && mouseY <= 250)
          {
               clickCase = 2; // Play animation 2.
               changePageFwd();
          }
     }
     else
     {
          ...
     }
}

void PageFlipOver(bool pageTurned)
{
     if (pageTurned)
     {
          // Update page index.
          indRight += 2;
          indPage += 2;

          if (indLeft + 2 < pages.Length)
          {
               indLeft += 2;
               leftBackground.mainTexture = pages[indLeft];

               if (indLeft + 2 < pages.Length)
                    pageBack.mainTexture = pages[indLeft + 2];
               else
                    pageBack.mainTexture = pages[indLeft];
          }

          if (!canFlipBkw)
                canFlipBkw = true;
     }

     canFlip = true;
}

void changePageFwd()
{
     if (indRight < pages.Length)
     {
          rightBackground.mainTexture = pages[indRight];
     }
     else
     {
          rightBackground.mainTexture = alpha;
          canFlipFwd = false;
     }

     if (indPage < pages.Length)
          pageFront.mainTexture = pages[indPage];
}
```

Any help is welcome, I've been stuck with this for two weaks and I can't find whats wrong.